# Hybrid app in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

Is it possible to build a single app that can work as native(GDK) and also insert cards into my timeline with Mirror API. Or i have to build separate apps for GDK and Mirror API.

I am aware that we can invoke a GDK app from a card inserted through Mirror API. But these are 
in essence two different apps interacting.

So is it possible that i can do the whole authorization through GDK app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly feasible to have a GDK-based app on Glass call the Mirror API to insert a card. Calling the [timeline.insert](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert) endpoint is not a big deal. You will have bigger issues if you're trying to handle callbacks since you'll need a stable IP address, but if all you want to do is insert cards with a URI to use as an intent trigger, that part is not an issue.

The issue you face, as you noted, is to do the authorization through Glass. This part is still immature in the GDK, and although there are some workarounds, there is nothing that Google provides yet that can help with this. Auth support is quite frequently requested, so expect something to address this as the GDK matures.